# How to know the variable percentage between two numbers?

Tags: statistics, percentages

1024 -----> 100%

940  -----> x%

800  -----> 0%

So (x) what percentage is it?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: $800$ isn't the $0\%$ of anything.

Comment: It sounds as though you want a linear function with the points $(800,0),(1024,100)$.  You should be able to go back to what you learned in middle school and be able to find the equation of a line given two points.  [See this page for example](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat150/notes/eqn_line/Equation_Line_Two_Points_Notes.pdf)

Comment: Even if you aren't able to remember how to do it yourself by hand, tools [like wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=equation+of+line+through+(800,0)+and+(1024,100)) can handle it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting into the context, and assuming a linear relationship then $y = 2.24x + 800$

$940 = 2.24x + 800$

$140 = 2.24x$

$x = 62.5\%$

Answer (score 0):

800 is $0\%$ ? It does not seem interesting here. To calculate $x$ you just have to calculate the ratio : $$ \frac{940}{1024} $$ which is around $91.8\%$. Don't hesitate to go there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage to understand more about percentages.

Comment: So how do I define 800 as 0%?

Comment: You can't say $800$ is $0\%$ of something. If you imagine $0\%$ of a ton of concrete, there's no concrete. There can't be $800$ kilos of concrete, that makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make myself understood. I translate the real problem that I have.

-> In a battery you have that (4.4v) is 100% battery, and that when it drops to (3.7v) is 0% is unloaded. Calculate what percent percentage is the scale if it is in (4.0v).